# JQuery grab value of hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of a hidden field using a selector on the input file field, as shown in my code below, but I am always getting undefined as the returned value, can someone please tell me what I am missing / doing wrong here? Thanks.

```
                    <form id="form1" method="POST">                            
                        <input type="hidden" id="docID1" name="docID1" value="1234">
                        <div class="fileUpload">
                            <button id="uButton" onclick="return false;">Browse</button>                                
                            <input id="uplA" name="uplA" type="file" class="upload" multiple />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Query:

```
var docIDInHiddenField = $('#uplA').parent('[name=docID1]').val();
console.log(docIDInHiddenField); //return undefined
```

Comment: Maybe is easy to use $('#docID1').val() ? No?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrect selector. hidden input is immediate previous sibling of `#uplA`s parent. you need to use:

```
 $('#uplA').parent().prev().val();
```